# Outlook 2010 Addin Build on VS2012 is not working after deploying

Tags: c#, c++, vsto, installshield, outlook-addin

I created a Outlook 2010 Add-In in VS2012 . For creating a installer i used install shield. Installer got created successfully and is running fine on my (development) system. But the same addin throws a error on deploying it on another machine.

> Error: Usual functionality of the add in are working but it throws a
>   error---  An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

**Note:** In my addin project i use a C++ dll for calling it's methods (through DLLImport). In my machine it works perfectly through the setup but in another machine it throws the error.

**Some More Info** : Both the system are 64 bit. The registry is getting created properly on target machine.

I have tried a lot but not able to find a result. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the bitness of your addin, the C++ DLL *and* Outlook match?

Comment: Addin is build with Target framework Any CPU, C++ DLL is win32 dll . Everything works Outlook 2010 (32 bit ) that is my system but not on Outlook 2010(64 bit) which is target system.

Comment: Presumably you need a 64 bit version of the C++ DLL to work with Office 64 bit as the Addin will be 64 bit and so cannot load a 32 bit module

Comment: From what i know the C++ dll is a win32 dll and normally it works for both X64 and X32.